# ¿Como hallar el ciclo anual para una serie de tiempo?

Tags: python, bucles

Estoy realizando un análisis estadístico sobre la radiación solar, esto significa que debo hallar los ciclos diurnos y anuales. Para los ciclos diurnos, se usa un **for** y funciono, pero para el ciclo anual no se utilizar el **for**, a continuación dejo los códigos utilizados.

---

**Ciclos diurnos:**

```
Serie = Radiacion_Proyecto
print Serie
2016-03-09 00:20:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:21:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:22:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:23:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:24:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:25:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:26:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:27:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:28:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:29:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:30:00   -1
...                  ...
2016-11-09 16:24:00  103
2016-11-09 16:25:00  105
2016-11-09 16:26:00  108
2016-11-09 16:27:00  110
2016-11-09 16:28:00  114
2016-11-09 16:29:00  117
2016-11-09 16:30:00  120
2016-11-09 16:31:00  121
2016-11-09 16:32:00  121
2016-11-09 16:33:00  120
2016-11-09 16:34:00  120
2016-11-09 16:35:00  118
2016-11-09 16:36:00  116
2016-11-09 16:37:00  114
2016-11-09 16:38:00  113

Median  = []
Mean    = []
perc25  = []
perc_75 = []
perc_10 = []
perc_90 = []

for i in range(24):

    a = Serie.between_time(np.str(i)+':00', np.str(i)+':59')
    a = a.values[np.isfinite(a.values)]
    Median.append(np.median(a))
    Mean.append(np.mean(a))
    perc25.append(np.percentile(a,25))
    perc_75.append(np.percentile(a,75))
    perc_10.append(np.percentile(a,10))
    perc_90.append(np.percentile(a,90))
```

---

**Ciclo anual:**

```
# Si fuera Ciclo Anual
for i in range(12): 
    FP = Serie(['2016 -' + np.str(i)])
    # La i son los 12 meses (Contador)
    #print i** No se como hacerlo!
```

Comment: puedes mostrar unos valores de entrada y salida de ejemplo para tener una mejor idea de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Hola! ya añadí algunos datos, con los ciclos diurnos busco hallar la media, mediana y percentiles de la radiación en un día. Ahora con el ciclo anual quiero hallar los mismo parámetros estadísticos, pero no logro aplicar bien la iteracion para que halle lo mismo pero en promedio por meses. Quedo atenta